# Different proof for a inequality

Tags: inequality

I have to prove the following

$$\left(\frac{k}{e} \right)^{k-1} \leq (k-1)!$$

without using $(1+\frac{1}{k})^k < e, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. I've tried using the following argument:

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!} ,  \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

therefore
$$e^x > \frac{x^n}{n!},  \forall x > 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$

this also means
$$e^{k-1} > \frac{(k-1)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!} $$

transposing the inequality gives us:
$$ \left(\frac{(k-1)}{e} \right)^{k-1}< (k-1)!$$

thats almost, what i want to prove.. is there a way to use this trick and finish the prove correctly ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: i tried using $e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{x^n}{n!}$ . With that we get $e^{k-1} < \frac{k^{k-1}}{k!}$, but that doesen't proof this exact inequality. Now I'm getting out of ideas

Comment: Isn't the inequality false for $k=2$?

Comment: The inequality is obviously true for $k \ge 3$ since $\left(\frac{e}{k} \right)^{k-1} \lt 1 \lt (k-1)!$

Comment: thank you for your comments. I mixed up the fraction and edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k=1$, we have
$$
(k-1)!=1=\left(\frac ke\right)^{k-1}\tag1
$$

For $k\ge2$,
$$
\begin{align}
e^k
&\gt\color{#C00}{\overbrace{\frac{k^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}}^{\frac{k^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\frac k{k+1}}}+\overbrace{\quad\frac{k^k}{k!}\quad}^\frac{k^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+\frac{k^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+\color{#090}{\overbrace{\frac{k^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}}^{\frac{k^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\frac{k-1}k}}\tag{2a}\\
&=\left(2+\color{#C00}{\frac k{k+1}}+\color{#090}{\frac{k-1}k}\right)\frac{k^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\tag{2b}\\
&\gt e\frac{k^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\tag{2c}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ use four terms from the Taylor series
$\text{(2b):}$ gather factors
$\text{(2c):}$ the terms in the parentheses are $\ge\frac{19}6\gt e$

Thus, for $k\ge1$,
$$
(k-1)!\ge\left(\frac ke\right)^{k-1}\tag3
$$

Answer (score 0):

Sketch $x\geq 3$:

We show :

$$\ln\left(\left(x-1\right)!\right)-\left(x-1\right)\ln\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)\geq 0$$

For that we rewrite the inequality as :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\ln\left(n-i\right)-\left(n-1\right)\ln\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\geq 0$$

Now we add a term as :

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(k-i)/(k-i)\cdot\ln\left(n-i\right)\right)-\left(n-1\right)\ln\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)\geq 0$$

So the function :

$$f(i)=(k-i)\ln(n-i)$$ is convex for $2n\geq k+i$ so we can apply weighted Jensen's inequality using bound for the harmonic sum .

So we are done .